# Creating an edge between a source point and a target point

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, canvas, html5-canvas

I am attaching a link to the code of what I have done so far, I encounter a problem when I want to create a connection from a source point to a destination point,
and also be consistent when the zoom changes.
My connections are created like this:

```
sourceId: number;
targetId: number;
sourcePortId: number;
targetPortId: number;
```

Each source / destination can have several ports defined for it, so I want the connections to be specific to the ports as well.

What I'm trying to achieve:[image]

source code: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-darkness-sf34q2)

thanks for the help :)

Comment: Please don't rely on outside code sites.  Post the minimal relevant code in the question.  The outside site can still serve as a fuller example and runtime testbed, but the question should be complete in itself.